# In WOW dungeon finder, how can the added player get to the existing group

Tags: world-of-warcraft

If someone leaves the party during in a dungeon, the rest of the party is queued in dungeon finder again. When a new player is found and added to the group (say I am that player), is it possible that I can directly get to the group rather than the dungeon entrance and run all the way up? It's a long way to run at least, and if the monsters are respawned, it's impossible to pass on my own.

Comment: It has been a while since i played the game but a warlock can summon players.

Comment: Normally, I think the player that joins a dungeon already in progress is brought directly to where the dungeon leader chose to re-queue. So this is at the mercy of that person, I believe. Maybe try right-clicking the dungeon finder icon on your mini-map, and teleporting out/back in?

Comment: @Ben I'm pretty sure teleporting out/in will always take you to the dungeon entrance. The only chance for the player to be teleported to the group leader is when he accepts the DF confirmation, at which point if the group leader is ineligible as a TP target, the new player loses his chance and will be placed at the entrance, just as Nick said in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that trash still has a re-spawn timer. However it is usually 2+ hours and it is often tied to bosses. Therefore if you kill a boss post trash, that trash will no longer be able to spawn.

In dungeons these days, the chance of a 2 hour + run are minuscule, so it just isn't seen any more.

It might appear that trash re-spawns, however it is more likely that this trash pack has been skipped by the group. Players run dungeons differently, take alternate routes, skip patrolling trash packs etc, so for a new player, it can certainly catch you out.

Regarding teleporting to a dungeon in progress. I am not 100% sure of how it works, but you sometimes will get teleported directly to the party mid dungeon.

Some factors which might decide why you get teleported to the start or the party could be:

- Where the dungeon leader is in the dungeon?
- If the dungeon leader has teleported out of the dungeon whilst waiting for new players there is nobody to teleport to when new players join.
- If the dungeon leader is in a vehicle etc. whilst in the dungeon, so there is no suitable place for the new players to teleport.
- If the new joiners are in a vehicle or quest flight and don't get instantly teleported to the dungeon. Manually joining puts you at the start.

Unfortunately I cannot confirm or deny the above, but just trying to give you a few potential reasons why you don't always teleport to the group and instead go to the instance portal.

Hope that helps.

Comment: There also seems to be 'checkpoints' that determine where you enter a dungeon.  Certain bosses killed typically, but not every boss, or passing certain cut scenes (like in [Gate of the Setting Sun](http://wowpedia.org/Gate_of_the_Setting_Sun)).  You will usually end up with the group unless under a condition like in the answer.